# Selecting Using XSL Stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="student-stylesheet.xsl"?>
<students>
    <student student-number = "1625344">
        <program> BIT </program>
        <study-model> on-campus </study-model>
        <student-type> domestic </student-type>
    </student>
    <student student-number = "2341235">
        <program> MIT </program>
        <study-model> distance </study-model>
        <student-type> international </student-type>
    </student>
    <student student-number = "1234567">
        <program> BMM </program>
        <study-model> on-campus </study-model>
        <student-type> domestic </student-type>
    </student>
    <student student-number = "8899009">
        <program> MIT </program>
        <study-model> on-campus </study-model>
        <student-type> domestic </student-type>
    </student>
    <student student-number = "0987654">
        <program> BIT </program>
        <study-model> on-campus </study-model>
        <student-type> domestic </student-type>
    </student>
</students>
```

Im trying to select the bottom student number and display it as a table with no header, just containing the student number, program, study-model and student-type.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Program</th>
        <th>Student Model</th>
        <th>Student Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="students/student/program"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="students/student/study-model"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="students/student/student-type"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my current sylesheet, it selects the very first student, not the last and is also missing the student number

Comment: XLS is not XSL . Don't mix it up.

Answer (score 1):

To get Student number you should put new TD as `<td><xsl:value-of select="students/student/@student-number"/></td>`. And if you want to get information of last student only, you should use predicate like  `<xsl:value-of select="students/student[last()]/@student-number"/>`

Comment: When I input the above, it renders as a blank white screen, so selecting nothing